# Vue Js conditional close of div tag

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I have an API returning chat messages in following object.

```
messages : [

    [
       sender: "John Doe",
       text: "Some message",
       sent_at: "2020-09-26",
       date_group: "Today",
    ],
    [
       sender: "John Doe",
       text: "Some message",
       sent_at: "2020-09-26",
       date_group: "Today",
    ],
    [
       sender: "John Doe",
       sent_at: "2020-09-26",
       date_group: "Today",
    ],
    [
       sender: "John Doe",
       text: "Some message",
       sent_at: "2020-09-25",
       date_group: "Yesterday",
    ],
    [
       sender: "John Doe",
       text: "Some message",
       sent_at: "2020-09-25",
       date_group: "Yesterday",
    ],
    [
       sender: "John Doe",
       text: "Some message",
       sent_at: "2020-09-24",
       date_group: "Thursday",
    ],
]
```

Instead of filtering and grouping `messages` by `date_group` and then sort them again by date and display, I just compare current message `date_group` with the previous message and if `date_group` is different then print it.

```
    printDateGroup(messageKey) {
        return this.messages[messageKey - 1] && this.messages[messageKey].date_group !== this.messages[messageKey - 1].date_group
            || messageKey === 0;
    },
```

Its working fine so far but all messages are now printed in a single div. Which causes trouble for sticky position of `date_group`.

Currently I print them with following.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column message-wrapper">
    <template v-for="(message, idx) in messages">
        <div v-if="printDateGroup(idx)" class="date-label">
            <span>{{ message.date_group }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="message-text">{{message.text}}</div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Instead I would like to render them in one `div` per `date_group` like following.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column message-wrapper">
     <div class="date-wrapper">
         <div class="date-label">Yesterday</div>
         <div class="message-text">Some message</div>
         <div class="message-text">Some message</div>
         <div class="message-text">Some message</div>
     </div>
     <div class="date-wrapper">
         <div class="date-label">Today</div>
         <div class="message-text">Some message</div>
         <div class="message-text">Some message</div>
         <div class="message-text">Some message</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried to open div and not close it like we do in `php` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in vue, but you can refactor your data model.

This is example of component that works as you need:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column message-wrapper">
    <template v-for="(group) in groups">
      <div class="date-wrapper">

        <div class="date-label">
          {{ group.name }}
        </div>
        <div v-for="message in group.messages" class="message-text">{{message.text}}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "index",
    computed: {
      messages() {
        return [
          {
            sender: "John Doe",
            text: "Some message",
            sent_at: "2020-09-26",
            date_group: "Today",
          },
          {
            sender: "John Doe",
            text: "Some message",
            sent_at: "2020-09-26",
            date_group: "Today",
          },
          {
            sender: "John Doe",
            sent_at: "2020-09-26",
            date_group: "Today",
          },
          {
            sender: "John Doe",
            text: "Some message",
            sent_at: "2020-09-25",
            date_group: "Yesterday",
          },
          {
            sender: "John Doe",
            text: "Some message",
            sent_at: "2020-09-25",
            date_group: "Yesterday",
          },
          {
            sender: "John Doe",
            text: "Some message",
            sent_at: "2020-09-24",
            date_group: "Thursday",
          },
        ]
      },
      groups() {
        const res = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.messages.length; i++) {
          if (this.printDateGroup(i)) {
            res.push({
              name: this.messages[i].date_group,
              messages: [this.messages[i]]
            })
          } else {
            res[res.length - 1].messages.push(this.messages[i])
          }
        }
        return res;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      printDateGroup(messageKey) {
        return this.messages[messageKey - 1] && this.messages[messageKey].date_group !== this.messages[messageKey - 1].date_group
          || messageKey === 0;
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Reason of this state is design of Vue.

Responsibility for data modeling is on side of js, templates needs contains only simplest operations like `for` or `if` but more advanced processing should be done in js part of components.

Comment: well yes, I did that but like I said if a chat has 100s of messages it will be filtered a lot of time which I am trying to avoid but will definitely use this approach as last resort.

Comment: You can observe problems with efficiency for 5k - 50k messages. Below this level you should not see any problems with time of rendering.